# Convergence of sum dependent random variables in $L^2$ with mean zero

Tags: probability-theory

Suppose that $X_1, \ldots$ were a sequence of random variables with $E(X_i)=0$ and $E(X_i^2)= \sigma_i^2$ and that $S_n := X_1 + \cdots + X_n$ converged in $L^2$. Does this imply $\sum \sigma_i^2 < \infty$?

Without some sort of bound on the $X_iX_j$ I'm not sure how to proceed.

Comment: Cauchy–Schwarz gives you a bound on $\operatorname{E}(X_i X_j)$. $\qquad$

Comment: @Michael Hardy: not a useful one.

Comment: Give yourself a positive, integer-valued random variable $\tau$ (a stopping time). Take $Y_1$ to be $\pm 1$ with probability $1/2 each$. Define $Y_k := (-1)^{k-1} X_k$. Finally, define $X_k := Y_k 1_{k \leq \tau}$. Then $(S_n)$ is bounded and converges almost surely, $\mathbb{E} (X_k) = 0$ for all $k$, and $\sigma_k^2 = \mathbb{P} (\tau >k)$ can decay as slowly as one wants.

Comment: No. Suppose $X_{2i-1}=-X_{2i}$ and $X_{2i}=f(i)Z$ for centered $Z$ with finite variance non-zero variance and $f=o(1)$. Then $S_n\to 0$ but $\sum f^2(i)$ can grow to $\infty$.